# Coturn fails on TURN (allocation timeout)

Tags: webrtc, turn, coturn

My coturn server always fails on turn. I've tried much variants of config, but nothing works(

Server is not NATted, and have only public IP.

Using next config:

```
domain=sip.domain.ru
realm=sip.domain.ru
server-name=sip.domain.ru

#listening-ip=0.0.0.0
#external-ip=0.0.0.0

external-ip=213.232.207.000
external-ip=sip.domain.ru
listening-port=3478

min-port=10000
max-port=20000

fingerprint

log-file=/var/log/coturn/turnserver.log
verbose
user=DavidMaze:Password
lt-cred-mech
#allow-loopback-peers

web-admin
web-admin-ip=213.232.207.000
web-admin-port=8090

cert=/usr/share/coturn/server.crt
pkey=/usr/share/coturn/server.key
cipher-list="ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384"
```

While calling, there is waiting for 60s, then in logs:

```
0: log file opened: /var/log/coturn/turnserver_2023-01-13.log
0: pid file created: /run/turnserver/turnserver.pid
0: IO method (main listener thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: WARNING: I cannot support STUN CHANGE_REQUEST functionality because only one IP address is provided
0: Wait for relay ports initialization...
0:   relay 213.232.207.000 initialization...
0:   relay 213.232.207.000 initialization done
0:   relay ::1 initialization...
0:   relay ::1 initialization done
0: Relay ports initialization done
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: turn server id=0 created
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: turn server id=1 created
0: turn server id=3 created
0: turn server id=2 created
0: IPv4. TLS/SCTP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IPv4. TLS/SCTP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: turn server id=5 created
0: turn server id=4 created
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/SCTP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/SCTP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IPv6. TLS/SCTP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: turn server id=6 created
0: turn server id=7 created
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IPv6. TLS/SCTP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: turn server id=9 created
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: turn server id=11 created
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: turn server id=14 created
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: turn server id=13 created
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IO method (general relay thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: turn server id=10 created
0: turn server id=15 created
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: turn server id=8 created
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: turn server id=12 created
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: 127.0.0.1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:3478
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:3478
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: 213.232.207.000:3478
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: IPv6. TLS/TCP listener opened on : ::1:5349
0: IPv4. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: 213.232.207.000:5349
0: IPv6. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: ::1:3478
0: IPv6. DTLS/UDP listener opened on: ::1:5349
0: Total General servers: 16
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (auth thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IO method (admin thread): epoll (with changelist)
0: IPv4. TLS/SCTP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:8090
0: IPv4. TLS/TCP listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:8090
0: IPv4. web-admin listener opened on : 213.232.207.000:8090
0: SQLite DB connection success: /var/lib/turn/turndb
5: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 213.232.207.000:3478, remote addr 188.162.5.118:34297
5: session 010000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
5: session 010000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
5: IPv4. Local relay addr: 213.232.207.000:11050
5: session 010000000000000001: new, realm=<sip.domain.ru>, username=<DavidMaze>, lifetime=600
5: session 010000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
6: session 010000000000000001: peer 213.232.207.000 lifetime updated: 300
6: session 010000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
7: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 213.232.207.000:3478, remote addr 87.103.193.000:56186
7: session 006000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
7: session 006000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
7: IPv4. Local relay addr: 213.232.207.000:16236
7: session 006000000000000001: new, realm=<sip.domain.ru>, username=<DavidMaze>, lifetime=600
7: session 006000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
7: session 006000000000000001: peer 213.232.207.000 lifetime updated: 300
7: session 006000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
15: session 010000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
17: session 006000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
26: session 010000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
27: session 006000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
36: session 010000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
38: session 006000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
46: session 010000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
47: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 213.232.207.000:3478, remote addr 188.162.5.118:23038
47: session 008000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
48: session 008000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorized
48: IPv4. Local relay addr: 213.232.207.000:16208
48: session 008000000000000001: new, realm=<sip.domain.ru>, username=<DavidMaze>, lifetime=600
48: session 008000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
48: session 006000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
48: session 008000000000000001: peer 213.232.207.000 lifetime updated: 300
48: session 008000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
50: session 010000000000000001: refreshed, realm=<sip.domain.ru>, username=<DavidMaze>, lifetime=0
50: session 010000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
50: session 008000000000000001: refreshed, realm=<sip.domain.ru>, username=<DavidMaze>, lifetime=0
50: session 008000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
50: session 006000000000000001: refreshed, realm=<sip.domain.ru>, username=<DavidMaze>, lifetime=0
50: session 006000000000000001: realm <sip.domain.ru> user <DavidMaze>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
51: session 008000000000000001: usage: realm=<sip.domain.ru>, username=<DavidMaze>, rp=5, rb=364, sp=5, sb=508
51: session 008000000000000001: closed (2nd stage), user <DavidMaze> realm <sip.domain.ru> origin <>, local 213.232.207.000:3478, remote 188.162.5.118:23038, reason: allocation timeout
51: session 008000000000000001: delete: realm=<sip.domain.ru>, username=<DavidMaze>
51: session 008000000000000001: peer 213.232.207.000 deleted
51: session 010000000000000001: usage: realm=<sip.domain.ru>, username=<DavidMaze>, rp=10, rb=592, sp=10, sb=1032
51: session 010000000000000001: closed (2nd stage), user <DavidMaze> realm <sip.domain.ru> origin <>, local 213.232.207.000:3478, remote 188.162.5.118:34297, reason: allocation timeout
51: session 010000000000000001: delete: realm=<sip.domain.ru>, username=<DavidMaze>
51: session 010000000000000001: peer 213.232.207.000 deleted
51: session 006000000000000001: usage: realm=<sip.domain.ru>, username=<DavidMaze>, rp=58, rb=7500, sp=9, sb=892
51: session 006000000000000001: closed (2nd stage), user <DavidMaze> realm <sip.domain.ru> origin <>, local 213.232.207.000:3478, remote 87.103.193.000:56186, reason: allocation timeout
51: session 006000000000000001: delete: realm=<sip.domain.ru>, username=<DavidMaze>
51: session 006000000000000001: peer 213.232.207.000 deleted
```

Also, 2 days ago i was having 403: forbidden IP. But it was fixed by commenting listening-ip

Comment: Where it 's failing ? candidate generation ? 
Did your port range open to public (10000-20000 from your config).
depending on your arch binding and public ip could be different . 
credential are correctly added?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed issue. For others:

1. At first, check issue on different browsers. I've detected, that call works on Mozilla Firefox, while don't work on Chromium-based browsers;
2. You can enable extra-verbose mode by `-V` flag (uppercase) or `--Verbose`. This can help, but logs are very annoying and no need to see them in 95% times;
3. While testing TURN-server via very popular tool [WebRTC sample - Trickle ICE](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/), you can see `authentication failed?` with `relay` in next line. This might not be problem, check this with other working TURN-server ([example](https://www.metered.ca/tools/openrelay/))
4. Check client's firewall for blocking ports of STUN/TURN servers, for port ranges of TURN. That was my case, client's firewall was blocking 24000-64000 ports.